# How to re order the dimensions on n-dimensional matrix in C? (Similar to permute(A,[2:n 1]) in Matlab )

Tags: c, arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am working a n-dimensional matrix (which being stored as a single dimensional array), I wish to reorder in its dimensions such that the leading dimension is now the last dimension.

> eg. if Dimensions(A) = 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 , I would want to change it to 4 x 5 x 6 x 3. 
>   This is similar to a transpose function for a 2-D matrix.

It can be implemented using permute function in Matlab
for n dimensional matrix A. I want the following tranformation

```
A=permute(A,[2:n 1])
```

How could I do it in C?

P.S. I am not looking to reshape the matrix but to actually move the elements in order to get the next dimension as the leading dimension.

Permute can be defined as

```
B = PERMUTE(A,ORDER) rearranges the dimensions of A so that they
%   are in the order specified by the vector ORDER.  The array produced
%   has the same values as A but the order of the subscripts needed to 
%   access any particular element are rearranged as specified by ORDER.
%   For an N-D array A, numel(ORDER)>=ndims(A). All the elements of 
%   ORDER must be unique.
```

Comment: You'll need `realloc` or use a static size with each dimension as big as worst case.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Could you please elaborate?
The problem is similar to rotating the cuboid( for a 3D matrix )in order to have the left face in front.

Comment: If you `malloc` each dimension to a certain length, you can use `realloc` to resize its length.  If you use a compiled array with a static size, you'll need to make each dimension's length as big as the biggest possible length.

Comment: If you have a `3 x 4 x 5 x 6` and want to change it to a `4 x 5 x 6 x 7`, where should the additional elements come from? This is not what `A=permute(A,[2:n 1])` does!

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, that was 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 to 4 x 5 x 6 x 3

Comment: @FiddlingBits I don't want to resize the existing order of elements but transpose the order of elements, also please check the correction that was 3 x 4 x 5 x 6 to 4 x 5 x 6 x 3

Comment: You can do it by [using a dope vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409991/use-a-dope-vector-to-access-arbitrary-axial-slices-of-a-multidimensional-array).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't want to try doing it in-place, but copying to a new array would be just a little more complicated than what you're already doing. I wrote a similar function for my apl interpreter.

If you have operations which can convert a list of indices and a list of dimensions into a single 1D index, and the reverse, converting a single index and a list of dimensions into a list of indices; then you just iterate through the 1D array, generate the index list using the source dimensions, apply the permutation to the index list, convert back to a single index using the destination dimensions and store the result in the destination array.

```
dest dimensions = permute source dimensions
for each element in source
    generate source indices from source index and source dimensions
    dest indices = permute source indices 
    generate dest index from dest indices and dest dimensions
    dest[dest index] = source[source index]
```

The pseudocode describes the algorithm, but here is an implementation: [array.c:transposea()](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/inca/blob/af7ca0a2db6c3b54f6521c598de449498ebcb8f3/olmec/array.c#L419). That function changes its argument, so for the above semantics, it should call `clone()` first and `copy()` after, to actually move the data around and leave the original undisturbed.

Comment: could you give an example or sample code to be more clear?

Comment: Edited with link to source.